# Check constraint on existing column with PostgresQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm trying to put check constraint on existing column.

Is there any way to achieve this from PostgreSQL?

Comment: Sure. What did you try so far? Did you check the documentation?

Comment: @frlan Postgres is a perfectly acceptable alternative name for PostgreSQL

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use `alter table` to add a new constraint:

```
alter table foo 
   add constraint check_positive check (the_column > 0);
```

More details and examples are in the manual:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html#AEN70043

**Edit**

Checking for specific values is done in the same way, by using an `IN` operator:

```
alter table foo 
   add constraint check_positive check (some_code in ('A','B'));
```

Comment: How do you put enum checks in the constraint?

Comment: What is an enum check?

Comment: My question was directed to @Passionate Developer

Comment: Like constriant for ("ABC", "DEF")

Answer (score 10):

If you are okay with (or want) Postgres to generate a constraint name you can use the following shorthand syntax.

```
ALTER TABLE foo
    ADD CHECK (column_1 > 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a new constraint with with `alter table` command. From [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-altertable.html) this example:

```
ALTER TABLE distributors 
ADD CONSTRAINT zipchk CHECK (char_length(zipcode) = 5) NO INHERIT;
```

You will have to replace constraint name as well as table name and content by your local requirements.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
create table test (
    id serial 
);

alter table test
add constraint id_not_null
check (id is not null);
```